# Regular expression to get only tag element in css styling string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to capture selectors with html elements in a style tag string in a nodejs environment.

I need to exclude strings that have # or . in front of them like css style selectors for class and id.

Something is wrong with my regexp, but I don't know where. I tried with negative lookback, but failed.

Current regex that catches all selectors in string: `/((([a-zA-Z0-9\[\]\=\"\'\.\-\_/:])*?)\s?\{)/`

Link to test: https://regexr.com/5cjl0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am trying to capture only selectors with html elements in a style tag string in a nodejs environment.

Answer (score 3):

If your file is really this well structured you may use

```
^(?![#.])\S*\s*\{
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/c4eui4/1/). Otherwise use a proper CSS parser instead.

Comment: I don't know how it will be structured, but most of the times this should work. Thank you! I am traversing a CSS string in a nodejs env, I don't think I need a CSS parser for now. The only issue with your regex is that in ```#outlook a{
 padding:0;
}``` the anchor tag doesn't get matched.

Answer (score 2):

### For a single regex selection - Use below:

- ^ ensures the next character is at the start of the string
- to reduce unnecessary use of additional A-Z in capitals, - /i ensures its any case

**example:**

```js
const reg = /^[a-z]+$/i
```

You can add in the $ at the end to be even more explicit as I have done above to ensure the last character is also [a-z]. Since all html tags have no special characters this would be suitable.

### For extracting the whole css object into multiple matches from a css file:

(If I have read your request correctly)

```js
const regTags = /(^|\n)\s*([a-z]+)\s*\{[^\}]*\}/gi
```

Would return

```css
applet {
  color: red;
}
```

or

```css
div {
  background: blue
}
```

### How to extract all tags using above regex

```js
const arrTags = [];
let arrMatch;
while (arrMatch = regTags.exec(myCssContents)) {
  const strTag = regTags[2];
  console.log(strTag);
  arrTags.push(strTag);
}
```

Comment: That's cool but from the test string I provided in the link I need to extract only ```a{```, ```img[src="https://example.com"]{```, ```table{``` and etc.

Comment: Just remove the last bit and use this: /(^|\n)\s*([a-z]+)\s*\{/gi